# spawn: command not found when I use expect to ssh login my remote server

Tags: bash, expect

In my Mac, I have installed `expect`:

```
$ brew install expect 
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: expect 5.45.3 is already installed
```

I write a bash script on my Mac:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f  (there I tried #!/bin/bash too)
set timeout 60
set host 103.212.12.76
set name root 
set password my_password

spawn ssh $host -l $name 

expect {
    "(yes/no)?" {
        send "yes\n"
        expect "password:"
        send "$password\n"
    }
    "password:" {
        send "$password\n"
    }
}

expect "#"
# test whether login to host
send "uname\n"
expect "Linux"
send_user "Now you can do some operation on this terminal\n"

interact
```

But when I execute my script on my Mac, I get error:

```
$ ./test01.sh 
./test01.sh: line 11: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "{": no such file or directory
./test01.sh: line 14: (yes/no)?: No such file or directory
./test01.sh: line 15: send: command not found
couldn't read file "password:": no such file or directory
./test01.sh: line 17: send: command not found
./test01.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./test01.sh: line 18: ` }'
```

It report `spawn: command not found`, but I installed the expect in my Mac.

I also tried change the `test01.sh` name to `test01.exp`, not work too.

```
./test01.exp 
./test01.exp: line 11: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "{": no such file or directory
./test01.exp: line 14: (yes/no)?: No such file or directory
./test01.exp: line 15: send: command not found
couldn't read file "password:": no such file or directory
./test01.exp: line 17: send: command not found
./test01.exp: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./test01.exp: line 18: `    }'
```

Comment: You don't appear to be executing the file you show; your file has doesn't have `spawn` on line 11 as indicated by the error message. The file you *are* executing appears to have a shebang like `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`.

Comment: @chepner What do you mean, my friend. You see, I really set `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`

Comment: @aircraft: There could be reason when `expect` is not found in the path mentioned in the interpreter. Replace `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` with `#!/usr/bin/env expect` and run the script as `expect test01.exp`

Comment: thank you I get it.

Comment: @aircraft Your error message says `line 11: spawn: command not found`. The code you show doesn't *have* a `spawn` command on line 11.

Comment: If you installed `expect` using **homebrew**, your first line should be `#!/usr/local/bin/expect ...` because **homebrew** installs to `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expect is not Bash. You need `#!/usr/bin/expect` or `expect /your/script.exp`.

Comment: If the path specified by the shebang didn't exist, the OP would get a specific error message to that effect; the script wouldn't be automatically run by `/bin/sh`.

Comment: You're right. People may not be telling all the truth when they ask questions. :)